# how to insert a row in the middle of the table. google sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api

I can't figure out how to add a row to a certain place always adds to the end of the table.

````
        {
            SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum valueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.RAW;
            SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum insertDataOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum.INSERTROWS;
            ValueRange requestBody = new ValueRange();
            requestBody.Range = range + "!A4:A";
            IList<Object> obj = new List<Object>();
            obj.Add("A2");
            obj.Add("B2");
            IList<IList<Object>> values = new List<IList<Object>>();
            values.Add(obj);
            requestBody.Values = values;
            SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(requestBody, spreadsheetId, range+"!A4:A");
            request.ValueInputOption = valueInputOption;
            request.InsertDataOption = insertDataOption;

            AppendValuesResponse response = request.Execute();
        }```
````

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append), values appended via `spreadsheets.values.append` are appended "**after the last row of the table**". With `append`, you cannot decide where exactly you want to add your data. The API looks for a "table" based on the input range you specify, as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#appending_values).

If you want to add a row in the exact place you want, you should first (1) insert an empty range and then (2) write your desired values to the empty range. You would have to do two successive requests:

- In order to insert the empty range where you want to append your data to, use the method [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) and in the [field `requests`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request), provide an [`insertRange` request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#InsertRangeRequest). Specify the row and column indexes you want to insert your range to (field `range`) and whether the previously existing cells should be shifted down or right (field `shiftDimension`).
- Second, once you have empty cells where you want your values to be, you can use [spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) to write those values (defined in the field `data`). Check [this guide to writing values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing) for a detailed explanation.

#### Reference:

- [Appending values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#appending_values)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [InsertRangeRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#InsertRangeRequest)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)
- [Writing](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing)